# Returning multiple struct from a method in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I've been trying to access a struct that has been passed into a variable outside of the method; however, I keep getting this error: `undefined method 'product_1'`.

Here's the code:

```
@page = get_fake_page
puts @page.product_1
```

and then in `get_fake_page` I have this:

```
Product = Struct.new(:slug, :id, :hover_category, :name, :editors_pick, :width, :height, :image, :image_1, :image_name_selection, :url_link)
def get_fake_landing_page
 product_1 = Product.new('#', '', '', '', false, '300', '300', '', '', '', '')
 product_2 = Product.new('#', '', '', '', false, '300', '300', '', '', '', '')
end
```

How should I be passing the struct from the method so I can access them outside of `get_fake_page`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return a hash from the `get_fake_landing_page` method:

```
def get_fake_landing_page
  product_1 = Product.new('#', '', '', '', false, '300', '300', '', '', '', '')
  product_2 = Product.new('#', '', '', '', false, '300', '300', '', '', '', '')

  {product_1: product_1, product_2: product_2}
end
```

And then use it like this:

```
@page = get_fake_landing_page
puts @page[:product_1]
```

To return a Struct instead of a Hash:

```
def get_fake_landing_page
  product_1 = Product.new('#', '', '', '', false, '300', '300', '', '', '', '')
  product_2 = Product.new('#', '', '', '', false, '300', '300', '', '', '', '')

  Result = Struct.new :product_1, :product_2
  Result.new product_1, product_2
end
```

Or better yet, OpenStruct:

```
require 'ostruct'    

def get_fake_landing_page
  product_1 = Product.new('#', '', '', '', false, '300', '300', '', '', '', '')
  product_2 = Product.new('#', '', '', '', false, '300', '300', '', '', '', '')

  OpenStruct.new product_1: product_1, product_2: product_2
end
```

And then use it like this:

```
@page = get_fake_landing_page
puts @page.product_1
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way to do this with structs rather than hashes?